# Looking to be able to look through header columns and reformat cells in those columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

my hope is to look through the headers of an Excel sheet and find those headers that include the word "DATE" or "DT" and reformat all of the data in that column to "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Existing code (lifted from comment)

```
Sub Macro() 
    Dim iLastRow As Integer 
    Dim i As Integer 
    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Row 
    For i = 3 To iLastRow 
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Select 
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm" 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify the logic would go something like this:

- go down b2 -> b until blank cell

- for cells that contain "DATE" or "DT" 

- go down that row -> go until blank cell

- change the format of all cells to mm:dd:yyyy h:mm

Comment: As of now I only have this that works for column A:

Sub Macro()

    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To iLastRow
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
Next i
End Sub

I'm having trouble making that a variable

Comment: why not directly `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"`?

Comment: My hope is to dynamically format based on headers, if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Sub Macro()
  Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
  For Each y In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With y
      For Each x In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If InStr(1, Replace(x.Value, "DATE", "DT", , , vbTextCompare), "DT", vbTextCompare) Then
          Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(2), x.EntireColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
        End If
      Next
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Just change the `For Each` line to fit your needs ;)

Comment: Thank you for this! Not sure what you mean though by changing the For Each. Sorry I'm very new to VBA.

Comment: It looks for the first row to find your headers... but if they are in the second one, you need to change the first parameter in `Cells` from 1 to 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is super helpful. If I was trying to get this to run through all the Worksheets would I also use a For Each?

Comment: You can, yes... it follows the same logic

Comment: Hi, you have any tips on this?

Comment: I changed the sub to fit your needs.